# explicitly_shared => no aggregation?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

When I use explicitly_shared, the stories don't aggregate. When I don't, the stories may not appear on the timeline at all. The story is the result of a button click by the user that explicitly means share this to fb, so it should always show up, but I don't want it to flood the profile if they click a few. What to do?

Comment: Does the button say Share on Facebook? If not it is not an explicit share.

Comment: Yes it was approved as an explicit share. Without aggregation it looks bad on the profile though. I'm inclined to turn off explicity_shared but then I have no idea what are the chances the story will be surfaced to friends.

Comment: @WizKid is there a reason it doesn't aggregate? Is this intended or can potentially be changed? Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming it is intended. If the person explicit shared something they obviously want it to be visible

Comment: @WizKid if they share 10 things it should be 10 stories? No way to say "shared 10 OBJECT on SITE"? Basically I need to choose between flooding the profile and not getting visibility (not sure how much I would lose in that option).

Comment: If the user want to share 10 things why wouldn't the user want all of them to be displayed

Comment: @WizKid because it will take over the entire profile. The content is important but the purpose of the product is to share several items at a time, and flooding the profile is definitely not what the user wants. Ideal behavior would be to guarantee that each item shows up, but to aggregate the stories into "shared x and Y and 10 other". I guess for now I will leave explicit share off and see if the exposure is too low. I think this is better than flooding the profile. Thanks for your responses and let me know if you think it is possible to aggregate.

Comment: No it is not possible to aggregate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to aggregate explicit shares, see comments above.